# How to set date range in zendx datepicker in zend?

Tags: php, zend-framework

Please let me know how to set date range in zendx datepicker in zend?

Comment: where  is the code ???

Comment: Finally i got the solution where i need to specify year range..$dob = new ZendX_JQuery_Form_Element_DatePicker('dob');
        $dob->setLabel('Date:')
                ->setJqueryParam('dateFormat', "yy-mm-dd")
                ->setJqueryParam('changeYear', "yy")
                ->setJqueryParam('yearRange', '1980:2013')
                ->setJqueryParam('changeMonth', "mm")